# mySQL 8, inserting non-null value

Tags: php, mysql

In the upcoming weeks I am going to update my mySQL database from 5.6 to 8.0.

Unfortunately my database has a lot of table with non-null values without default value.
As I saw in the mySQL documentation in this case if I try to insert a row, and I don't define every column value, then the query gives an error, and won't insert the row.

Example:
--id (int, auto increment) -- name (varchar, non-null, no default value) -- some_number (int, non null, no default)

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO example_table (name) VALUES (:name)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
```

If I'am right, this query should return an error, and shouldn't insert anything (because the "some_number" value was not given).

But as I saw in my test environment, it gives only a warning, and the query inserts the row with "0" value as "some_number" column.

Is it really required to specify non-null value for each column when inserting ?

Comment: What warning exactly?

Comment: `Is it really required to specify non-null value for each column when inserting`...well that would be the logical thing to do. Otherwise the behaviour you get is either undefined, if the server doesn't complain, or you get an error. Otherwise what is the point of having non-null fields?

Comment: There are a lot of data what I can provide later with an update. For example there is a table with football players where is some basic info: name, age, etc.. But there is other columns which value I want to provide later: fore example: "last_transfer", or "nickname". 
Unfortunately in the last years I didn't setup these columns as NULL. So, the main question is to should I update every non mandatory column as a NULL column (or provide a default value to them), before update to mysql 8 (will it be a fatal error, or only I get a warning)?

Comment: The warning: "Warning: #1364 Field 'stadiumcapacity' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: You can test what will happen using a simple sandbox environment online, like dbFiddle or SQL Fiddle, one of those. Set it to mysql 8, make a sample table with non null fields and try inserting data

Comment: And then if it crashes, yes you have a decision to make. I don't know all of your business logic, but from what you've said it sounds like making those fields nullable might make sense. Ultimately it's up to you how to decide to implement it though.

Comment: The biggest issue is that the "NULL" values will effect to my mobile applications. My api provide now empty results, but if I change these columns to NULL, it will provide NULL values which will cause crash of the app.. 

So that's why this so complicated...

But maybe the solution is to 
1) provide default values for every column instead of NULL
2) update to 8
3) in the newly created datatable I have to add NULL values and handling these in the mobile app too.

Comment: I guess you could make your API translate null to empty strings before it returns data. Or you must adjust the code in the mobile app to cope with nulls. Or you must set default values in the database for all these columns. It's really up to you, as I said.

Comment: not reproduceable, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/rzAq2iY4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another alternative.

Data types have an implicit default, so if you don't define a default for a given column, it can still convert invalid values (e.g. NULL for a NOT NULL column) to the implicit default.

The strict behavior to return an error in MySQL 8.0 is only the default. You can change it, so it behaves like your current version. You can do this by changing the SQL mode.

Read for more information:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-implicit

You can change the SQL mode either globally on your MySQL instance, or on per-session basis, removing strict mode if you want.

But you have better control if you ALTER TABLE to define a default for your NOT NULL columns, if you want to allow inserts without specifying a value. For example, you could make the default value something other than the data type's implicit default.

I don't think this is really that complicated. If you have NOT NULL columns, then you can't store NULL in them. You must do one of the following four choices:

- Modify the column to allow NULLs
- Specify a non-NULL value
- Define an explicit default for each NOT NULL column
- Change the SQL mode to be non-strict, and rely on the data type's implicit default